# ¿Cómo definir Collation que ignore acentos en SQLite usando Entity Framework en .NET 5 (C#)?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos SQLite en una aplicación Windows Forms programada en C# y usando .NET 5. Para realizar consultas, modificar, etc. sobre la base de datos hago uso de Entity Framework Core. Me gustaría que, al realizar comparaciones con los datos de la base de datos utilizando Linq, me ignore los acentos. He estado mirando en internet y, por lo que he visto, tengo que definir un Collation que me ignore los acentos, pero exactamente en SQLite no sé cómo hacerlo. Al construir el contexto de mi base de datos en el método `OnModelCreating` he añadido la sentencia `modelBuilder.UseCollation("NOACCENTS");`, pero me sigue sin funcionar. Me ha quedado algo así.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.UseCollation("NOACCENTS");
  //A partir de aquí  está la definición de las tablas y campos de mi BBDD
}
```

Sin embargo, no me funciona, ¿qué puedo hacer para ello?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo hacerlo de esta manera personalizada:

Primero creas una **clase estática** que tendrá el o los métodos encargados de estandarizar las palabras:

```
public static class Fonetica
{
   public static string EliminarTildes(string texto)
    {
        return texto.Replace('á', 'a').Replace('é', 'e').Replace('í', 'i').
                     Replace('ó', 'o').Replace('ú', 'u');
    }
}
```

Esta clase tiene un método encargado de sustituir las tildes por vocales sin tilde utilizando la **función** **Replace**.

Y a la hora de buscar con **Linq** harías una consulta de esta forma:

```
texto = Fonetica.EliminarTildes(texto.ToLower());

var lista = from a in db.Entidad.ToList()
            where Fonetica.EliminarTildes(a.Campo.ToLower()).Contains(texto)
            select a).ToList();
```

En esta consulta **Linq** estandarizamos tanto la palabra a buscar como los registros que tiene la tabla, es decir eliminamos las tildes en ambos lados, para asegurarnos de que haya una mayor coincidencia en la búsqueda.

Esto tiene como ventaja que puedes hacer métodos de búsqueda aún más complejos, por ejemplo, en la **clase** **Fonetica** podrías tener un método como este:

```
public static string SustitucionSimple(string palabra)
    {
        return (palabra.Replace('ñ', 'n').Replace('á', 'a').Replace('é', 'e').Replace('í', 'i').
                        Replace('ó', 'o').Replace('ú', 'u').Replace('ü', 'u').
                        Replace("aa", "a").Replace("ee", "e").
                        Replace("ii", "i").Replace("oo", "o").Replace("uu", "u").Replace("ge, je").Replace("ce", "se").
                        Replace(" ", "")).Trim();
    }
```

Este método sustituye vocablos teniendo en cuenta como suenan, por ejemplo ahora podrías buscar **"Gerardo"** o **"Jerardo"**, **"Cepillo"** o **"Sepillo"**, esto estandariza aún más la búsqueda y ofrece mejores coincidencias en la búsqueda, y es bueno ya que la persona puede tener faltas de ortografía y escribir mal las palabras, esto es algo así como un **buscador fonético** el cual puedes complejizar tanto como desees.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Mil gracias @Japv!!!!